# How long and formal should a paper revision letter to the editor be?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, communication

I submitted a paper to a journal, they replied saying that they consider it worthy to be published if I corrected a few minor errors, and I have corrected them so it's ready to be sent back.

Someone told me that you should include a letter to the editor stating this and thanking the reviewer. I've never done this before, so I'm not sure about several factors like formality/length/specifics. For example, do I just say "I've made the requested changes" or do I have to list them more specifically?

Could someone show me a boilerplate letter of this type, or point me to a resource that talks about it?

Comment: Aside from the usual pleasantries ("we found the reviewers' comments very helpful and thank them for their time") usually your letter will address each individual comment made by each reviewer for the purpose of satisfying the editor you heeded the advice (or had reasons not to do so). I suppose if it were a very short list of simple corrections it would be sufficient and practical to say you executed them all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The editor needs this letter because she has to make sure that you have adequately taken the reviews into account. She is not going to read your paper to make sure you did.

Thus, in your letter, you have to address each comment and

- explain how you implemented it or
- explain your good reasons why you chose not to implement it.

[Here](http://matt.might.net/articles/peer-review-rebuttals/) is a method for writing a letter that ensures that all reviewer comments are systematically addressed.

Comment: Just to add:  you can cut and paste their comments and write what you did after each one.  "We changed this line to read 'blah blah'"